# Can a specific version be modified on npmjs?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the revision on the https://replicate.npmjs.com/_all_docs
Is it possible that one old or latest version changes and with that the revision changes too? Or the revision just changes when a new value is updated?
For this package:
https://registry.npmjs.com/zrd3
I have the info:

```
"modified":"2022-01-24T15:21:42.641Z",
  "created":"2016-05-04T18:10:18.369Z",
  "0.6.4":"2016-05-04T18:10:18.369Z",
  "0.7.0":"2016-06-15T00:03:11.841Z",
  "0.8.0":"2016-06-15T00:32:59.891Z",
  "0.8.1":"2016-07-03T05:06:20.994Z",
  "0.8.3":"2016-12-22T20:34:08.857Z",
  "0.8.4":"2016-12-22T20:39:29.564Z"
```

What can this modified be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research about it, the revision change means that we may have new versions for a specific package.